# Configurar MySQL no docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

Quando pego um arquivo sql de uns 80 mb e tento fazer o dump no MySQL Workbench

Ele dá:

Error Code: 2006. MySQL server has gone away

Minha configuração do docker-compose está assim:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.1
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:     
      - ./etc/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf  
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "123"
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql  
volumes:
  mysql-db:
```

Meu arquivo etc/mysql/my.cnf na pasta local e não mysql está assim:

```
[client]
port      = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[safe_mysqld]
err-log      = /var/log/mysql/mysql.err

[mysqld]
server-id=10
log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=pop
binlog-ignore-db=mailstats,mysql,pop.bak,radius,radius.bak,test

user      = mysql
pid-file   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port      = 3306
log      = /var/log/mysql.log
basedir      = /usr
datadir      = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
language   = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-locking

# key-buffer define quanto de memória será armazenado para
# gravar dados de consultas do MySQL. Quanto maior a quantidade
# de memória disponível, melhor será o desempenho do servidor
set-variable    = key_buffer=312M

set-variable    = max_allowed_packet=64M

# table_cache é muito importante, este número deve ser o dobro
# do número definido pela variável max_connections
set-variable    = table_cache=20000

set-variable    = sort_buffer=1M
set-variable    = record_buffer=1M
set-variable    = myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
set-variable    = thread_cache=8
set-variable    = thread_concurrency=8

# max_connections vai definir quantos sub-processos e 
# consequentemente quantas conexões seu MySQL suportará
# simultaneamente. Por incrível que pareça, quanto maior este
# número, menor será o load do seu server. Tente restringir este
# para um número baixo e você verá que loucura está fazendo
set-variable    = max_connections=10000

set-variable    = net_write_timeout=30
set-variable    = connect_timeout=2
set-variable    = wait_timeout=30

# Read the manual if you want to enable InnoDB!
skip-innodb

[mysqldump]
quick
set-variable   = max_allowed_packet=64M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
set-variable   = key_buffer=64M # era 16M
```

Gostaria de configurar para o meu mysql do docker aceitar arquivos grandes

Meu projeto completo está [aqui](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/docker-mysql-php73-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, pela descrição do erro, isso geralmente ocorre quando o servidor excedeu o tempo limite e fechou a conexão ou  quando o tamanho do pacote excedeu o tamanho máximo dos pacotes que podem trafegar nas threads do MySQL. No seu caso ao fazer o restore do banco de dados.

Tente o seguinte:

Altere a o valor desta variável:

```
set-variable    = wait_timeout=30
```

Para um valor que consiga suprir o tempo do seu upload. e altere também essa outra variável:

```
set-variable    = max_allowed_packet=64M
```

Para um valor compatível com o tamanho do seu pacote. No seu caso, acima de 80M.

Faça as alterações no etc/mysql/my.cnf e reinicie o servidor de bancos de dados MySQL para que as alterações passam a valer.

Comment: Mesmo mudando, quando vou no workbench continua com esse valor '4194304'
 quando dou o comando `'SELECT @@max_allowed_packet;` e então continua dando esse problema
`